# how to read all video file with parent directory in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to read all .mp4 and .mkv file from my local storage how can i get in flutter?[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker
Multiple files

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);

if (result != null) {
  List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

Multiple files with extension filter

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc'],
);
```

[image: package]